# How do I parse strings into their data types?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I want to parse strings as follows:

```
"1.0" # => 1.0 (Float)
"1" # => 1 (FixNum)
"hello" # => "hello" (String)
"true" # => true (TrueClass)
"false" # => false (FalseClass)
```

I have the following code:

```
def parse_value(val)
  raise ArgumentError, "value must be a string" unless val.is_a? String
  if val.to_i.to_s == val
    val.to_i
  elsif val.to_f.to_s == val
    val.to_f
  elsif val == 'true'
    true
  elsif val == 'false'
    false
  else
    val
  end
end
```

This does what is needed, but it seems horrible and inefficient. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: There is a simple elegant way to do what you want using the method `e**l`. But I hesitate to write that answer because there are too many stupid users on stackoverflow who will downvote such answer for sure.

Comment: @sawa Eval won't work for all of those inputs (`"hello"`)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I missed that. You are right. Actually, the OP's question is unclear on that point. How does that lead to a string? When it cannot be interpreted otherwise? If so, that means you can't have a string `"true"`, etc.

Comment: @sawa: I often use this kind of parsing for config files / CSV, for example. In those use cases, having a string `"true"` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What makes `"hello"` to make sense while `"true"` not making sense?

Comment: @sawa: imagine, say,  a column "ignore_fields" in a CSV file. It can have value "false" or value "no" or value "field1, field2, field3". You get the idea?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah. And how is `"hello"` useful?

Comment: @sawa: in my case, it would be interpreted as a name of a field to ignore.

Comment: "hello" represents any random string that is not "true" or "false", and cannot be converted into a float or an integer.

Comment: @Gagan Gami See what I mean? Your answer is the best answer, and I would like to upvote it, but it is too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of using `eval`, you can't get much more concise/elegant code, I'm afraid. Here's a variant using `case/when`, but it's a lipstick on the same pig.

```
def parse_value(val)
  raise ArgumentError, "value must be a string" unless val.is_a? String
  case val
  when /\A\d+\z/
    val.to_i
  when /\A\d+(\.\d+)?\z/
    val.to_f
  when 'true'
    true
  when 'false'
    false
  else
    val
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain these regular expressions to me please?

Comment: @JohnLinux: those match integer and float numbers. For more info, feed them to [http://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tE3tU3/1) or read your favorite regex documentation.

Comment: +1 for regex101.com, very useful. I was aware they matched the numbers, was asking more specifically about the tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
def parse_value(val)
  raise ArgumentError, "value must be a string" unless val.is_a? String
  case val
  when /\A\d+\z/         then val.to_i
  when /\A\d+(\.\d+)?\z/ then val.to_f
  when 'true'            then true
  when 'false'           then false
  else val
  end
end
```

I wrote this as a more concise version of the Sergios answer.
I would like feedback on whether this would be against Ruby style guidelines.

Comment: I personally don't use "then". Too much typing (and the need to align them)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval` along with a regular expression:

```
def parse_string(val)
  raise ArgumentError, "value must be a string" unless val.is_a? String
  val =~ /\A(\d+(\.\d+)?|true|false)\z/ ? eval(val) : val
end

parse_string '1.0'   #=> 1.0
parse_string '1'     #=> 1
parse_string 'hello' #=> "hello"
parse_string 'true'  #=> true
parse_string 'false' #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(s)
  i = Integer(s) rescue nil
  return i if i
  f = Float(s) rescue nil
  return f if f
  return true if s == "true"
  return false if s == "false"
  s
end

arr = %w| 1 1.0 true false hello |
  #=> ["1", "1.0", "true", "false", "hello"] 

arr.each { |s| e = convert(s); puts "#{e.class}: #{e}" }
  # Fixnum: 1
  # Float: 1.0
  # TrueClass: true
  # FalseClass: false
  # String: hello
```